# How to assign new values to global variable from inside a function

Tags: function, julia, global-variables

I want a function to assign a new value to a global variable:

```
value = ""

function edit_value(v::String)
    value = v
end
```

However, it does not assign the global `value` the new value. Julia creates a new local variable `value` inside the function.

How can I modify the global variable inside a function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do that with the keyword `global`

```
function edit_value(v::String)
    global value = v
end
```

Keep in mind that global variables, especially when changed within a function, should be [handled with care](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/performance-tips/#Avoid-global-variables).